# Laravel: Trying to get property ' ' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm retrieving some variables to be shared with all my views, for this I'm using laravel's view composers.

However when trying to access values in my blade templates I get the following error:

"Trying to get property 'socialLinks' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Costadog4\resources\views\inicio\index.blade.php)"

After doing this:

```
{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks->twitter }}
```

My GlobalsComposer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Globals;
use App\Models\Post;
use Auth;
use Config;

class GlobalsComposer
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
    }


    public function compose(View $view)
    {

        $globals = Globals::all()->pluck('value', 'name'); 

        $socialLinks = [

            'twitter' => config('globals.twitter'),
            'facebook' => config('globals.facebook'),
            'instagram' => config('globals.instagram'),

        ];

        $layoutLinks = [

            'classPosts' => Post::withCategory('Clases')->take(10)->get(),
            'behaviourPosts' => Post::withCategory('Conducta canina')->take(10)->get(),
            'trainingPosts' => Post::withCategory('Formación')->take(10)->get(),

        ];

        $loggedUser = Auth::user();

        $allGlobals = compact('globals', 'socialLinks', 'layoutLinks', 'loggedUser');
        //dd($allGlobals);

        $view->with('allGlobals', $allGlobals);
    }
}
```

This is the shape of $allGlobals:

```
array:4 [▼
  "globals" => Collection {#1036 ▶}
  "socialLinks" => array:3 [▶]
  "layoutLinks" => array:3 [▶]
  "loggedUser" => null
]
```

Comment: So you see that `socilaLinks` is __array__. Then why do you use `->` notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socialLinks` is an array you can use it as :

`{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks['twitter'] }}`

**OR**

```
    $socialLinks = [

        'twitter' => config('globals.twitter'),
        'facebook' => config('globals.facebook'),
        'instagram' => config('globals.instagram'),

    ];

    $socialLinks = collect($socialLinks); // Convert array to collection
```

Now this should work:

`{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks->twitter }}`

Tip :
Use `optional()` method while using chained method

`{{ optional($allGlobals->socialLinks)->twitter }}`

This eliminates the error "Trying to get property of non-object" and return `NULL` if socailLinks is missing

**OR**

if using php 7

`{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks->twitter ?? "www.defaulturl.com" }}`

Conversion to Collection is recommended as your data will be persistent inside the `$allGlobals` collection

Answer (score 3):

***socialLinks*** is an array. Change it to this:

```
{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks['twitter'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`allGlobals` and `socialLinks` are both arrays so you can't use `->`, use `['key']` instead:

```
{{ $allGlobals['socialLinks']['twitter'] }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I should be:

```
{{ $allGlobals->socialLinks['twitter'] }}
```

because `$allGlobals` is an object but `$allGlobals->socialLinks` is an array. 
so if you try to access it  like this `$allGlobals->socialLinks->twitter` then you'll get an error

> trying to access property non object